# Wait without blocking for event to fire

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

**Edit: No, this question has not been answered in the post linked above.**

If I have this pseudocode:

```
// do some stuff first
wait until ClassName.EventName fires without blocking
// do the rest of the code
```

Is there a way of doing that in C# with .NET 4.0 ?

Edit:

I have downloaded the Async Targetting Pack and I am trying to do this with that.
(My project is targetting .NET 4.0.)

I've added code like this now.

```
private static async void WaitAsyncNoBlock()
{
    await dynMapServLayer.IsInitialized;                 
}
```

So that it is called like this.

```
// do some stuff first
WaitAsyncNoBlock();
// do some more stuff
```

But I get the error message, "Cannot await Bool."

Comment: Subscribe to the event and do the rest in the handler...? I'm not quite sure I'm *getting* it though...

Comment: you can do this via a thread. But it seem wierd to me... the event will be catch automatically when fired so why do you want to wait for it?

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor I think he is wanting Async-Await functionality in .NET 4.0

Comment: "wait until . . . without blocking" - seems like a contradiction?

Comment: @TimothyShields Have you used `await` in .NET 4.5, it does exactly that. It will block your code execution, but it will not block the message pump, when your task finishes it will pick up where it left off.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have used it a bunch, although I didn't realize that's what he meant. Semantically, an `await` means "this 'thread' of execution should wait until this asynchronous task is done." Of course, it's much more efficient than that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I tried to use "await" but it says that the type or namespace await could not be found.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor. I'm wanting to avoid running it in the handler because the handler is not logically or semantically related to what happens next. I used to have it run in the handler, but now I'm tryign to get out of that.

Comment: @TimothyShields, Scott is correct. I want other code to be able to run while waiting for the event to fire.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Here I originally only asked for the how the general thing is done. The code was edited in later because somebody asked to see the real code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about using `await` in your code like you can in [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx) you can use the [Async Targeting Pack](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) from Microsoft to add that functionality to your .NET 4.0 programs.

Comment: I've downloaded VS 2012, so I should be able to use await. But I get an error saying that the type or namespace for await could not be found.

Comment: Did you install the Async Targeting pack from NuGet, you either must use .net 4.5 or download the Async Targeting Pack to get await to work.

Comment: If you did install it but you are still getting the error check out the [FAQ here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx). It sounds like you may be having "Issue 4". They describe how to work around (basically put your code in a separate DLL instead of in the main web page code)

Comment: I'm about to try the AsyncTargetting pack. My project is targetting .NET 4.0 so I think that this is the only way to go. Is there any harm in having the AsyncTargeting pack with VS 2012 since they both have the same abilities?

Comment: Async is not a ability of vs2012, it is an ability of .NET 4.5.

Comment: I think you can use AsyncTargetting pack in vs2010, you just need to install the [NuGet plugin first](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c), the NuGet plugin just happens to come pre-installed on vs2012.

Comment: Nevermind, just saw on the page discription page for the package "This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010"

Comment: I've edited the code to show the Async and Await that I've tried and an error message, "Cannot await Bool." Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I would go read some tutorials on how to do use `await`, it will help explain what you need to do. You will likey need to wire up your events that sets the initiazer to set a [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) as completed.

Comment: Excellent. I think you've got me headed in the right direction. Much appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a handle to anotate the event. And, when it fires, you run your code.

For Example:

```
MyForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosed);
```

And:

```
void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e){
//Here you put the rest of code
}
```

Comment: Can't do that. I specifically do not want the rest of the code to run in the listener.

Comment: @Beebok Can you edit your original post and add more details explaining what you want to do. It is very hard to understand what you want.

Comment: See here to understand why I don't want the rest of the code to run in the subscriber. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659582/how-to-wait-until-an-event-is-finished-without-blocking-execution-in-the-ui/16661622#comment23987749_16661622[/link]

Comment: I just want the rest of the code in that method to not run until after the event has fired.

Comment: If the code isn´t in the listener, it will run in sequence. Put your real code.

Comment: I've added the real code